# replace alphanumeric values in a column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame that looks like this:

```
a, b, c
4f5t-4656, x, y
3jsu-56hj, x, y
gfhdu670-9, x, y
fgfj-6fhf, x, y
ELE, x, y
ELE, x, y
```

My goal is to replace all the alphanumeric values in column a by the the letters 'LCD'. I have tried:

```
df['a']=df['a'].replace([a-z0-9-], 'LCD', regex=True)
```

but I am getting the "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

What's the problem with the code? can anyone help?

Comment: Quote around regex ? `replace('[a-z0-9-]',`

Comment: What is the expected output? I doubt just adding the quotes will give you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that you don't want to replace each matching character by LCD, but the whole series of characters, thus you probably want to add a `+` quantifier in your regex (in addition to the missing quotes that give you the SyntaxError):

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace('[a-z0-9-]+', 'LCD', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     a  b  c
0  LCD  x  y
1  LCD  x  y
2  LCD  x  y
3  LCD  x  y
4  ELE  x  y
5  ELE  x  y
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to wrap this expression in quotes

```
df['a'].replace(r'[a-z0-9-]', 'LCD', regex=True)
```

I think that should work